# Trying to make a Mysql Password table that can be encrypted for security and then reset if user needs to reset a forgotten password

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to make a table for passwords that can be called upon by a foreign key from the table user so that they can type their password and it will be placed in the table and encripted securely. I have heard of encrypting it with a hash; and I searched all around but have no clue how to use it other than what i saw in this video http://www.sqlshare.com/Player.aspx?vid=626&plid=&searchid=177388

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

In short, you use a one way hash such as sha1 or md5 to turn the password into a piece of text. That can not be undone. You store the hash in your database.

When the user enters their password, you hash their password in the same way, then check if that's in your database.

If they want to reset the password, you make up some random string that's pretty long, then email them at the account your registered them with. They go to a link with that string as the GET parameter. You check if it's the right string, and if so ask for a new password, hash it, and store in the database.

To get this working securely, you should read up on md5, sha1 and salting hashes.

Comment: +1 Nice summary.  A couple of quick questions for clarity - 1) Do (/'can') you email everyone the same 'reset' password?  2) Is that 'reset' password hashed itself?  Presumably not and its value is checked before hashing and then comparison.  Would be nice to add for clarity. :)

Comment: You'd want to generate (and store in the database) a unique reset password, otherwise you could reset everyone else's accounts. Yes, you'd want to hash it.

Answer (score 0):

What Rick says is spot on, obviously there are more methods to authenticating the user in order to change the password other than " some random string that's pretty long".

If you want to know more about one-way hashes and have an example to work through, I would suggest having a look at this book:
[WickedCoolPHP](http://nostarch.com/wcphp.htm)

It has helped countless number of times both with quick scripts to work from and with better understanding PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help I will look into it Rick´s answer is logical and makes perfect sense know I just have to figure out how to implement it in code. Hope the book helps though isnt it on php what i am making it on is sql

Comment: You use php coding to perform many of the tasks with your data from your SQL database.
You can also use php to check that the data meets a certain standard before Inserting it into your data base so you can avoid nasty sql injection attacks.

This is all explained in the first two chapters of the book.
I can assure you that the book will become your best friend, at least for the next few months ;)

Comment: Cool Thanks I will definitely take a look at it then